# What's the difference between the different flavors of linux?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I'm not extremely linux familiar, but I've heard all these different types, like Ubuntu, Debian, Red hat, Fedora, etc. I assume some are sequential releases, but what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Linux" properly refers to the OS kernel.

By "different flavors of linux", you are referring to different Linux distributions. A "distribution" is a complete operating system -- a particular packaging of the kernel with various other utilities, services and shells that provide the rest of what users expect from an operating system.  [nik's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/68264/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-flavors-of-linux/68265#68265) provides some good links to start with.

The differences between distributions are in the particulars of

- what a distribution is designed to accomplish,
- which versions of what tools it includes to achieve that goal, and
- how it chooses to handle configuration and packaging.

A distribution aimed at desktop users typically includes the X-window system, a desktop environment, a printing subsystem, networking components, etc.  One designed for servers often doesn't include X or a desktop environment, but adds services that aren't needed on a desktop (webserver, database, network filesystems, etc).

Comment: Richard Stallman would say that "Linux" improperly refers to the OS http://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html ;-)

Answer (score 4):

1. Wikipedia: [Comparison of Linux Distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions)

   - Further reading at [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/)
   - Similar question: [What are the differences between major Linux distributions? Will I notice?](https://superuser.com/questions/135/what-are-the-differences-between-major-linux-distributions-will-i-notice)